# Mage::log() does not log in all files used by Magento?

Tags: overrides, log

I have overwritten `Sitemap.php` in `app/code/local/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php`. The file seems to be used, if I remove all contents, there's an error as expected.

I copied the complete content of the standard `Sitemap.php`, with one single change. I added

```
public function generateXml() {
    Mage::log('test');
    ...
}
```

When I do this anywhere else, it prints `test` in `var/log/system.log` as expected, only in this file, it does not log the message.

Any help is greatly appreciated

---

***EDIT***

using

```
Mage::log('text', null, <file>, true);
```

does not work either

Comment: Is logging enabled in system configuration? Is `var/log/` writable by your web user (`apache`, `httpd`, `www-data`, etc.)

Comment: logging works in `SitemapController.php`, so yes, it is. and yes `var/log` is writable. Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Perhaps Mage core isn't loaded? Maybe try Mage::app()

Comment: @TimHallman how would magento work without core? The site works just fine

Comment: Because it's sitemap.php. Try logging in `app/code/local/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Observer.php` rather than `Sitemap.php`

Comment: @TimHallman one sec, so you're saying I can't log in any file which is used by Magento in some way or another? Then I'm not understanding the log system correctly I fear

Comment: It's just that Mage::run() has to happen first, but honestly I'm not quite sure about sitemap

Comment: @TimHallman well ok, it does work in the observer. I guess I just can't debug with mage::log there. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would assume, the file is loaded but the method is not called. So just set a breakpoint (or bad way a `die()`) into your method and make sure it is called.

After magento is initialized `Mage::log` at least with the `$force` parameter writes its log

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I guess I'll open another question why my generateXml is not loaded. Because no, it does not reach the breakpoint.

Answer (score 32):

Use `Mage::log('text here', null, 'system.log', true)`.
That should work all the time.

Comment: Or for instance a sitemap.log in case you don't want your sitemap logs mixed with random stuff .

Comment: @JulienLachal. True. The filename can be anything.

Comment: please see my edit, this does not work either

Answer (score 2):

Another guess here - the sitemap generation is generally triggered by a cronjob. If your cronjob runs under a different user than your webuser and doesn't have the permissions to write to your existing system.log file you wouldn't get any entries.

Comment: True, but I'm testing it by just clicking "generate" on the sitemap admin page. So I'd assume he should have permission. EDIT: it does not work either if the permission is set to 777

Answer (score 0):

Give the right permit to your `var/` folder:

```
chmod -Rv 777 var/
```

So use like this code below:

```
Mage::log(print_r($yourTest), null, 'customLogFile.log', true);
```

> The **print_r** will prevent some errors related to the type of your
>   variable.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in any function or file

> Mage::log( "Your message - ", null, 'your-log-filename.log');

this file will be created at your inside your root folder path like

> /var/log/your-log-filename.log

hope it will work for you.